# How to instantiate an object in locals?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a module which uses a variable of object type

```
variable "table" {
  type = object({
    name    = string
    read_capacity = number
    write_capacity = number
    arn = string
    policy_name = string
  })
}
```

I am not able to understand how to initialize this and pass to the module

```
locals {
  table_dev_configs = {
  arn = "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:123456789:table/my-table-dev"
  name = "some_name"
  policy_name = "some_policy"
  read_capacity = 20
  write_capacity = 20
  }
}


module "my_table_dev" {
  source = "../../modules/my_table"
  table = local.table_dev_configs
}
```

I mean `locals.table_dev_configs` looks I am initializing a Map instead of an object.

### ../modules/my_table.tf

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "my_table" {
  name           = var.table.name
  read_capacity  = var.table.read_capactity
  write_capacity = var.table.write_capactity
  hash_key       = "id"
}
```

Doing it the *Map* way gives me this error:

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
 read_capacity  = var.table.read_capactity
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.table is a object, known only after apply
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "read_capactity".
╵
```

What is the right way to initialize an object?

Comment: You forgot to explain what's the problem with the code. Any errors?

Comment: The error originates in a `read_capacity  = var.table.read_capactity` line. But in your code there is no such line. This means that your question lacks details and is unclear.

Comment: I can't post the entire file structure, will be too big.

What is not clear from the docs, is how do you pass an instantiation of an object? 

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#using-input-variable-values

All the examples are for variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
  read_capacity  = var.table.read_capactity
  write_capacity = var.table.write_capactity
```

it should be

```
  read_capacity  = var.table.read_capacity
  write_capacity = var.table.write_capacity
```

Comment: Doh! Thank you.

So maps are objects are initialized the same way then.

Comment: The `{ ... }` syntax is an object constructor. It can also be used to initialize maps because the Terraform language can automatically convert from object to map as long as all of the attributes of the object can all be converted to the same element type.